# how can i get a sql xml saved file using c#?

Tags: c#, sql, xml

i have this stored proc and it's work fine

```
alter PROC DBXMLSTRUCT 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @xmlStr XML;
set @xmlStr =
(select '[Stok]' [@DataBaseName],
(select t.table_name [@TableName],
(select c.COLUMN_NAME [@ColumnName] 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
where c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
for xml path('Column'), type)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
for xml path('Table'), type)
for xml path('DataBase'),type)
SELECT @xmlStr = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\XMLDBStruct.xml', SINGLE_CLOB) as XMLDBStruct(BulkColumn)

SELECT @xmlStr
END
```

how can i get this saved xml file using c# 
but by special way that's return a handsome xml doc like the same one in sql server

Comment: Might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899353/xml-raw-data-returned-from-sql-server-2005-not-correct-when-calling-from-net

Comment: What is a "handsome" xml document, exactly?

Comment: @Preston Guillot ("handsome" xml document) i mean not messy

Answer (score 2):

Just write your results to a file. You are already returning formatted xml

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xml);
xdoc.Save("myfilename.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con))
    {
        XDocument results = new XDocument(
       new XElement("results"));

        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "MyStoredProc";
            conn.Open();
            var count = 0;
            using (XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    results.Root.Add(XElement.Parse(reader.ReadOuterXml()));
                    count += 1;

                }
            }

            return results.ToString();

        }
    }
```